# XPages : How to get document collection for dominoView datasource with 'search' property in SSJS

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I filtered out XPages view with 'search' option. Then I'd like to access all of the documents by SSJS.

If I access the bound Notes view by database.getView("ViewName"), the view is not searched and could not get the searched result.

How can I access the document collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dominoView data source is just a wrapper that runs calls on the underlying view to return a subset of entries to display in a view component (Data Table, View Panel, Repeat, Data View etc). Consequently, unless the `rows` property is set to a large enough value to get a handle on all responses, you’re unlikely to be able to access what you want that way.

The best approach will be to run the search on the backend view in SSJS / Java.

See https://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-xpages-views/ for a more detailed explanation of the different elements involved and their inter-relationships.

Comment: Thanks, so the only option to get the document collection on SSJS side is to run the same search again in SSJS code. Correct?

Comment: Let me re-emphasise, you don’t currently have a DocumentCollection anywhere on the XPage. You have a dominoView consisting on (by default) 30 rows of a ViewEntryCollection which is either all entries or a filtered set of entries matching search criteria. If you want to use the same contents in both places, you need to step back a level and consider the source that you’re binding the viewing component to. If no search has been requested, use the dominoView, otherwise use a DocumentCollection or more likely a ViewEntryCollection (possible with Data View or Repeat, but not View Panel).